# Why is the second line of a description item indented further?

Tags: lists, indentation, description

When I compile this code, the second line is indented further. I would like it to be level with the first line. I wish to keep the numbering optional and manual, therefore the use of description is very convenient.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}
        \item[1.] This item takes up two lines and the second line has an extra indent which I would like to remove, is there any way I can do that ?
    \end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the default. Maybe what you want is `enumerate` (automatically numbered, so don't need `\item[1.]` but only `\item`) instead of `description`.

Comment: `description` is for items like  `\item[The String Theory] Bla bla bla ...`  . In  numbered list the label grows to the left, but such long labels must grow to the right, taking  space of the first line, therefore the remaining text does not start in a fixed point, but when the label end.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve even lines.  The question is how do you want to format the label?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This item takes up two lines and the second line has an extra indent which I would like to remove, is there any way I can do that ?
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item[{\makebox[\labelwidth][l]{1.}}] This item takes up two lines and the second line has an extra indent which I would like to remove, is there any way I can do that ?
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{description}
        \item[{\makebox[\dimexpr \leftmargini-\labelsep][l]{1.}}] This item takes up two lines and the second line has an extra indent which I would like to remove, is there any way I can do that ?
    \end{description}

\end{document}
```